# How do you echo an image from a webserver directory based on the $_SESSION['propertyid']

Tags: php, html, image, session

I'm building a real estate website in HTML and PHP.

My question is: how can I display images from a webserver directory and only show the images associated with a specific property id number?

I am registering the property id number through a session called `$_SESSION['propertyid']`.

Below is my for listing the images from my directory.  It currently displays all the pictures in the directory, but I only want to display the images that are associated with the session id number.

```
<?php

$dir = "../uploads/";

//open directory to read dir
if ($opendir = opendir($dir))
{
    //read directory
    while (($file = readdir($opendir)) !== FALSE) 
    {
        if ($file!='.'&&$file!='..')
            echo "<img src='$dir/$file' height='150' width='150'><br><br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: How are the images associated with the id in the first place?

Comment: `<img src="<?php echo map_property_id_to_file_path($_SESSION['propertyid']); ?> ">`

Comment: then your images should have that propertyid in their file name. Otherwise you have nothing to make the connection ;)

Comment: so you will have something like: `echo "<img src='". $dir. "/". $file . $_SESSION['propertyid'] . "' height='150' width='150'><br><br>";`

Comment: if this works, I will post this as an answer for other users to see and use ;) so please let me know

Comment: Hi Ares, unfortunately that didn't work. I still display all the images in the directory. The way I have it setup is that I have an upload script that renames the image to the property id its associated to and then adds a random number at the end... incase more than one file is being uploaded for the same property. An example of a file in the directory is 941070974_1508421.jpg where the first piece before the "_" is the property name and the second piece is the random number.

Comment: Marc B - it seems to work, but I return what looks like a broken image. Do I need to add the file extension? Also How can I add a wild card so that it returns all images with the same property id? example, I have two images with the same property id but I add a random number at the end so a user can upload more than one picture

Comment: Im almost there. this will return one picture based on the session name: <div><img src="../uploads/<?PHP echo $_SESSION['propertyid'].'.jpg'; ?>" alt="photo" width="100" height="100" border="0" /></div>